# No application records were found using Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

hi i am totally going mad. searched a lot but still getting the same error. i created app in Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS SDK 7.1. i correctly do every step and archiving my ios is good. in iTunes connect i uploaded everything and my app is status is "prepare for submission" just need to upload my ios app. when i hit validate or distribute button i get the error "Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode."

my Validating iTunes connect username and passwords are same as in iTunes connect site user id and password. i dont know what to do. kindly help me i am half mad.

Comment: What about the Certificates, App Ids and Provisioning Profile. Are you sure you are doing correct ?

Comment: Have you checked that you have used exactly the same bundle identifier (e.g. com.mycompany.myapp) in both Xcode and iTunes connect?

Comment: Yes everythng is ok but still getting this error.. i saw a post where they say that from 1 june onward distribution of app required ios sdk 8?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple October 20, 2014](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a):

> Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.)

Update to the current Xcode and select the current sdk. You can still select an earlier iOS version as the deployment target.

Comment: Lets try to update to yosemite and use the latest version of xcode... hope so solve my problem.